# Como alterar a cor do background do body em um template VTEX IO?

Tags: css, e-commerce

Como posso alterar a cor de fundo de um template VTEX IO na qual a estrutura é feita em JSONC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vá no diretório `styles/configs/style.json` e procure a chave `semanticColors.background.base` e altere para a cor desejada.